# smallest monic polynomial that induces the zero function modulo $p^k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I came across this problem while doing an assignment from my number theory class, and hope that someone can point me to a correct direction!

1. Define $d(n)$ to be the degree of the smallest **monic** polynomial that is identically zero modulo $n$. From some searches and readings, I believe *identically zero modulo n* means this polynomial *induces zero function modulo n*, is this correct?
2. Then, for prime $p$, I have found that $d(p) = p$ as many other questions have indicated. Also, I have proved that if $n' \mid n$, then $d(n') \leq d(n)$ by noting that if $f(a) = 0 \bmod m$ for all $a \bmod m$, then $f(a') = 0 \bmod n'$ must also be true for $a' \in (\mathbb{Z}/n'\mathbb{Z})$.
3. From this result, I believe we can say that if we have $n=pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes and suppose $p>q$, then $d(n)=d(p)$?
4. Then, if $n=p^k$, namely $n$ is some powers of a prime. Can we say something about $d(n)$? Right now, I'm able to show that $d(4)=4$, but cannot figure out how to generalize a pattern.

Comment: If $n$ is a product of distinct primes, with largest prime factor $p$, then $(x - 1) \dotsm (x-p)$ shows $d(n) \le p$. On the other hand $d(n) \ge p$ by point 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lowest degree polynomial vanishing on the integers mod $n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389875/lowest-degree-polynomial-vanishing-on-the-integers-mod-n)

Comment: @ronno I'm still not sure how to generalize to $n$ that is some powers of a prime